# Customising localhost URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, localhost, hosts-file

I want to test a web app locally. Since its using facebook api. I want of have the same url as the live one.

The url of the live one in in the following structure.

https://app.example.com/example

I want to imitate the same URL in my local system. I tried with etc/hosts file. But I couldn't get the link right.

this is the only thing I was able to get

I wasn't able get the https and folder name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the facebook API does not use your etc/host DNS setting.. Set up a full test enviroment with valid domain, and regist it to facebook.

Comment: _“the facebook API does not use your etc/host DNS setting”_ – for most of the stuff it doesn’t have to, because authorization etc. happens inside the client browser. Only if you are using functionality where there is actual callbacks from Facebook’s servers to your server happening, that would be a factor (such as real-time updates for example). Otherwise, testing most stuff with a locally set up domain works just fine.